# javascript document.write() removes the html from page and display result in a blank page

Tags: javascript, document.write

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript - what are alternatives to document.write?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4537963/javascript-what-are-alternatives-to-document-write)

i am creating a javascript function which i want to execute after few seconds but when it executes it removes all the page content and display only that result which i am displaying using document.write()  here is my javascript code.

```
<script language="javascript">
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
 xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
 xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

setTimeout(function(){
xmlhttp.open("GET","some.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("offer");
var page = parseInt(x.length) / 10;
document.write("<div class='pagination_btn_cont'>");
for (i=1;i<=page;i++)
{ 
 document.write("<div class='pagination_btn'>"+i+"</div>");
}
document.write("</div>");
},10000);

</script>
```

when i open the webpage its display all the content of the page but after 10 seconds the page will become blank and display only the numbers which i am getting from the loop.

any suggestion how can do this task.

Comment: Suggestion: don't use `document.write` and consider using a [JS library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ajax_frameworks#JavaScript)

Comment: what should i use then to display the button properly after few seconds without removing previous content on the page?

Comment: [Alternatives to document.write](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762202/alternatives-to-document-write); [What are alternatives to document.write](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4537963/javascript-what-are-alternatives-to-document-write)

Comment: @raina77ow - this code actually displaying the page numbers by fetching xml data from a file inside a div. i have put there setTimeout() function to load after few seconds and display inside a div but its display in a blank page rather than inside a div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use innerHTML in javascript.
It use to insert data to particular div without affecting page contents.

Example:

```
var results = "";
for(var i=1;i<=10;i++)
{
     results += "<div class='pagination_btn'>"+i+"</div>";
}
document.getElementById("your result show div id").innerHTML = results;
```

**you can specify `$('.pagination_btn').bind("click")...` inside your document.ready**

Comment: i have tried that also but inside innerHTML we cant use loop, it display only single button

Comment: it works. its display the buttons, but here i think a news problem is coming- i have create a jquery click function on that div with its class name "pagination_btn" now that function is not working

Answer (score 3):

Use innerHtml to change text of a specific element.

HTML

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

javascript

```
document.getElementById('container').innerHTML += '<div>content</div>';
```

or you can use jQuery library, life will be much easier:

```
$("#container").append("<div>content</div>");
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body').innerHTML += '<div id="parent" class="pagination_btn_cont">';

for (i=1;i<=page;i++)
{ 
 document.getElementById('parent').innerHTML = "<div class='pagination_btn'>"+i+"</div>";
}
```