# Replace inline JavaScript function call with element

Tags: javascript, html

Is something like this possible?

```
<head>
<script language="javascript">
function createElement(this) {
    var ele = document.createElement('div');
    ele.setAttribute('style', 'display: inline-block; width: 100px; height: 20px; background: rgb(35,150,215);');
    ele.setAttribute('onclick', 'alert(\'Yay!\');');
    this.replaceWith(ele);
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
blah blah blah some text <script language="javascript">createElement(parentTag);</script> blah blah more text.
</body
```

What I am trying to do is make a button that I can dynamically add INLINE to any page where this function is called. It will have other parameters than just the script tag to replace. I want the button to go exactly where the function was called.

Comment: Then you may want to use `document.write` instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Alternatives to document.write](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762202/alternatives-to-document-write)

Comment: @bfavaretto Wow, that seems too obvious. Just one of those things I don't use often enough to think about. Thanks! *facepalm*

Comment: This looks messy TBH. Why not separate logic from markup? Create a button in html, add the styles in css, and use JavaScript to add/remove classes or events where necessary. Your current code will eventually become a nightmare to maintain.

Comment: However it is possible to avoid document.write, take a look at the suggested duplicate link. @elclanrs I believe the OP is looking for a script block that can be inserted by a third party anywhere within the body, and have some element inserted right there.

Comment: @elclanrs that button I'm going to be dynamically adding is a lot more intricate than in this example. And I don't want to have to update every page that has the button on it every time I want to alter the buttons functionality. I suppose I could just as easily do it server-side though.

Comment: @Charles If you can do it server-side, it's certainly cleaner.

Comment: Apparently I enjoy overly complicating things.